# Confusion about notation for orientation of boundary

Tags: notation, manifolds, definition, manifolds-with-boundary

I am reading "All the math you missed" by Thomas A. Garrity, second edition. In the chapter on Divergence Theorem there is the following fragment:

> Here the derivative $\frac{df}{dx}$ is integrated over the interval
> $$[a, b] = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a\leq x \leq b\},$$
> which has as its boundary the points a and b. The orientation on the boundary will be b and -a, or
> $$\partial [a, b]=b-a.$$

I am confused by the fact that $\partial$ was defined previously as boundary of manifold, which is a set, while $b-a$ is clearly not a set. Is this notation overloaded (possibly implicitly) and varies depending on the context or am I simply misunderstanding something? Or perhaps there is typo in the book and the statement should be different? I have seen some lecture notes that used symbols like $M$ for manifold, $\imath$ for its orientation and $\partial\imath$ for induced orientation of $\partial M$, but this notation is still not the same as the one I am struggling to comprehend.

Comment: There are different notions of "boundary" indeed.  See here, for instance, where the minus signs are built in:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_homology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundary of an interval is indeed a set of 2 oriented points, let's write it as $\partial [a, b] =  \left\{a_-, b_+ \right\} $. "Integrating" a function $f$ over this set should be just evaluating it on the 2 points times the corresponding orientation, so $f(b)-f(a)$

Comment: Relevant question answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4742156/73934