# How is the fundamental theorem of calculus dependent on orientation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential-forms

Using standard Lebesgue integration, we can write:
\begin{equation}
\int_{(a,b)}f'(x) d\lambda = f(b) - f(a)
\end{equation}

There's no orientation on the left hand side of the equation, yet on the right we take $f(b) - f(a)$ as opposed to $f(a) - f(b)$.

Due to what exactly is that the case? In what piece is the "orientation" $a \rightarrow b$ encoded?

//

My thoughts:
I'd guess it's due to the fact that the derivative is in some sense defined in a slightly arbitrary way - both $\lim \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and $\lim \frac{f(x)-f(x+h)}{h}$ make sense. But at the same time, it doesn't seem that arbitrary - it's natural to assume that numerator/enumerator order should be preserved, i.e. $\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{(x+h) - (x)}$ is the natural choice. So I think I might be missing something.

Comment: "There's no orientation on the left hand side of the equation" -- how so? The interval $(2,3) = \{x \in \mathbb R: 2<x<3\}$ is rather different from $(3,2) = \{x \in \mathbb R: 3<x<2\} = \emptyset$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Lebesgue's integral doesn't care about orientation. And what you wrote are two different sets, nothing related to having two different orientations.

Comment: @NDB: I think Lebesgue's integral cares about whether you integrate over a non-empty interval or an empty set.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg That's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Jake See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Relation_with_measures) for a short discussion.

Comment: @NDB: I don't think so. OP claims that they can flip the roles of $a$ and $b$ on the LHS without changing the result. I say they cannot. I admit there is another point to be made here, but I think it is worth pointing out first and foremost.

Comment: You might formalize orientation for intervals through $[a,b] = -[b,a]$, such that $\int_a^b = -\int_b^a$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I don't know where you are reading them saying that they can swap $a$ and $b$. They are asking why the FTC presents $a$ and $b$ in that order. It has nothing to do with what you are saying.

Comment: @Jake1234 As you observed, the derivative has $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$, or the other variations that you wrote. Note, that what is crucial for the order in the right side, is that in the definition of derivative, the numerator $f(x)-f(y)$ and the denominator $x-y$, the positions of the $x$ and the $y$ are the same. This is what ultimately causes the result $f(b)-f(a)$ appear in that order.

Comment: Assuming that the integral exists, you can check the value for particular simple functions, a Riemann sums. For example divide the interval in equal pieces and select values of $f'$ that are the mean values of $f$ on those little intervals. So, you get sums $\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_2)}{x_1-x_2}\mu((x_1,x_2))$. As you can see, you can always write all the fractions with the same order of the $x_i$. And the sum telescopes.

Comment: @NDB: OP writes "There's no orientation on the left hand side of the equation, yet on the right we take $f(b) - f(a)$ as opposed to $f(a) - f(b)$." I read that as saying that on the LHS one can flip $a$ versus $b$ but on the right hand side one cannot. And my comment said, you cannot flip them on the LHS either.

Comment: By the way, the easiest case here is: Why is $\int_{(a,b)} 1 d\lambda(x) = b-a$ and not $=a-b$. And as far as I am concerned, that is the definition of the Lebesgue measure. As per @LeeMosher's answer.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg It is really $\lambda((a,b))=|b-a|$. Moreover, your $b-a$ vs $a-b$ has nothing to do with the question. The result is really $\frac{x|_b-x|_a}{b-a}\lambda((a,b))=\frac{x|_b-x|_a}{b-a}|b-a|=b-a$. The $f(b)-f(a)$ being really the $x|_b-x|_a$, not the $\lambda((a,b))$. It is actually the derivative, being defined as "quotient of increments" and those increments being taken in *the same order* in the domain and the co-domain, what causes the order of the result in the FTC.

Comment: @NDB $\lambda((3,2))=0\neq|2-3|$

Comment: @FShrike I don't know what that has to do with anything. The set $(3,2)$ is not the set $(2,3)$. $\lambda(\mathbb{R})=+\infty$ too. (!?)

Comment: Indeed. I object to "$b-a$ vs $a-b$" having nothing to do with the question, it is the whole question. I object to "$\lambda((a,b))=|b-a|$" since this is wrong unless you propose new notation

Comment: @FShrike Again, it is not the Lebesgue measure of the interval what causes the order of evaluation in the FTC. In the result, the measure is merely a factor multiplying the part that really has the difference $f(b)-f(a)$. At most, the fact that measures are non-negative is its only role. Read my comment two above this one.

Comment: @NDB I don't want to get philosophical and argue about "x is what's responsible for y" when we're being this vague - if we were to be precise, FTC is true due to multiple factors, one of them being how the derivative is defined. But it seems a bit misleading to imply that the definition of the derivative is somehow the main reason. It doesn't seem to "encode" any particular orientation as a concept - we look at $1\cdot \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x -y}$ on a sufficiently small set $I$- this a perfectly natural concept that has no direct assumptions on the set, or its orientation.

Comment: @Jake1234 The definition of derivative (its sign) is precisely what encodes whether $f$ is orientation preserving or reversing. This, is ultimately a consequence of the increments in the denominator and the numerator being written in the same order.

Comment: [See](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability#Orientability_of_differentiable_manifolds), how the Jacobian determinant (just $f'$ in one dimension) is used to define when transition functions are orientation preserving.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4742254/1198684), which you should accept as *the* answer. The last paragraph there put it as clear as water. The answer by Lee Mosher is just nonsense.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg There is no FTC in $\int_{(a,b)}1d\lambda=b-a$. This is part of the definition of Lebesgue's integral. To see this as an instance of FTC you first need to see the function $1$ as a derivative of a function. It is there where a choice of orientation is made, to make FTC look like this. Note that (although nobody does it) FTC could be $\int_{(a,b)}f'=f(a)-f(b)$. You just need to define $f'$ using $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{y-x}$. Equivalently, as the coefficient of $df$ in the chart $x\mapsto -x$. This chart gives the other orientation of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You could abstract away the discussion of difference quotients (and therefore orientation) if you think about derivatives are representing the slope of the line of best fit at a point, so the issue is possibly even a bit deeper.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Slope is usually defined from derivative. If you do it the other way around, what is slope? And the choice doesn't go away. Do we assign NorthEast-pointing arrows positive or negative values to be their slopes?

Comment: @NDB: You seem to want the question to boil down to, "For $f(x)=x$, why do we use definitions so that $f'(x)=1$ and not $=-1$?". That's a fair question with interesting thoughts attached to it. But can you accept that one can also boil the question down to, "Why is $\lambda((a,b))=b-a$ and not $a-b$"? I think it's interesting to see how these two thoughts complement each other here.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Orientation is a concept in mathematics. If they didn't intend to refer to the concept, perhaps. But if they did, there is no orientation involved in $\lambda((a,b))=b-a$, and there is in the $f'$. If the use of orientation in the post refers to the concept, [it is a question with substance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Relation_with_measures). It is choosing between answering a well defined question and one with undefined terminology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you interpret the expression $\int_{(a,b)}f'(x)dx$ as a Lebesgue or Riemann integral, than the integral itself does not depend on orientation, as Deane's answer explains. The derivative $f'$, however, *does* depend on orientation. There are a few ways of seeing this.

In the difference quotient $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{(x+h)-x}$, the two subtraction operations encode a sense of orientation, but they do not "cancel out". The numerator is a subtraction in the codomain of $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, while the denominator is a subtraction in the domain, and we are only concerned with the orientation of the domain here.

Alternately, we can see precisely where orientation is invoked by instead considering a function $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ where $M$ is a connected Riemannian $1$-manifold (which happens to be $\mathbb{R}$). The Borel measure $\mu$ compatible with the metric (such as the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$) can be defined without choosing an orientation, but this only allows us to integrate functions $M\to\mathbb{R}$. The derivative $df:M\to T^*M$ is a $1$-form on $M$ and there are two possible choices of trivialization $T^*M\to M\times\mathbb{R}$ compatible with the metric. There is a standard choice for $M=\mathbb{R}$, but without such a choice (i.e. an orientation) we cannot view $f'$ as an integrable function.

Comment: Yet another alternative is to use the metric to induce on $M$ the canonical $1$-pseudoform $\omega=\sqrt{g}|dx|$, which allows one to integrate a function $f$ by integrating the $1$-pseudoform $f\omega$, which is equivalent to integrating against the measure $\mu$. But again you cannot integrate $1$-forms, only $1$-pseudoforms and functions.

Answer (score 5):

Although I suggest that you don't overthink this too much, I do like the manner in which you formulated your question, asking how orientation is *encoded* in the Lebesgue integral.

Intuitively, the difference between the positive and negative orientations on an interval $[a,b]$ can be detected using the *displacement* from the initial endpoint to the terminal endpoint, which by definition is equal to the terminal endpoint minus the initial endpoint. Under the positive orientation, the initial endpoint is $a$, the terminal endpoint is $b$, and the displacement is the positive quantity $b-a$; whereas under the negative orientation, the initial endpoint is $b$, the terminal endoint is $a$, and the displacement is the negative quantity $a-b$.

One place (*the* place, perhaps) that the orientation of intervals is encoded is in the formula for lengths of intervals in the real line: for any $a<b$ in $\mathbb R$, the length of the interval $(a,b)$ is, by definition, $b-a$, which *just so happens* to be equal to the displacement of the positive orientation on the interval $[a,b]$. And, of course, lengths of intervals comes into the definition of the Lebesgue integral when one defines the Lebesgue outer measure, which is then used to define Lebesgue measurable sets and the Lebesgue measure itself, which is then used to define the Lebesgue integral of simple functions, which  is then used to define the Lebesgue integral in general.

Comment: This is wrong. There is no orientation involved in saying that the Lebesgue measure of $[a,b]$ is $|b-a|$.

Comment: I didn't say that the Lebesgue measure of $[a,b]$ is $| b-a |$. I said that for all $a<b \in \mathbb R$, the length of $(a,b)$ is $b-a$.

Comment: You can then use that, together with the definition of Lebesgue measure, to deduce that the Lebesgue measure of $[a,b]$ is $|b-a|$, if you want to.

Comment: Again, no orientation is involved at all in Lebesgue integral. It is also irrelevant whether you wrote absolute value or not. I added the absolute value to make a point.

Comment: @Jake1234: I added some additional details regarding the encoding of the orientation in the definition of the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Without even reading it, I know that what you wrote is wrong. Again, there is no orientation in Lebesgue integral. There is no orientation in Lebesgue integral. There is no orientation in Lebesgue integral.

Comment: @NDB There's no orientation needed to describe the measure of some set, but assuming the measure should be non-negative (which is a natural, intuitive demand, as we want to minimize foolery we would get due to $ -1 \cdot -1 = 1$), it does end up being the case that $\int_I 1 d\lambda = \lambda(I) = sup(I) - inf(I) = b - a$ (which can be understood as a consequence of how the real numbers are constructed/defined, particularly the ordering and subtraction operation).

Comment: @NDB This special FTC has no concept of a derivative anywhere, and so it's an even more basic observation of what I'm asking in my OP - it's a scenario where on the left hand side, there is no idea of an orientation, and yet for some reason, the right hand side does have a particular order. The orientation is encoded somewhere.

Due to this, this seems like a more intrinsic explanation of where the orientation is "encoded", rather than the sign of the derivative - which seems like it should be defined in such a way, so that it agrees with this definition. Though of course that's subjective.

Comment: @Jake1234 Ok, I have said already all that needs to be said. Now it is on you and all others trying to see orientation in Lebesgue integral or even in the measure of intervals. Read the last paragraph of [Kajelad's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4742254/1198684), and if that doesn't make it clear, there is nothing else I can do. Pay special attention to the part where it remarks that the $f'$ wouldn't make sense to be put directly inside a Lebesgue integral.

Comment: @Jake1234 And by the way, $\int_{(a,b)}1d\lambda=\lambda((a,b))$ is not FTC, but merely the definition of Lebesgue integral. To make it agree with FTC, or rather the other way around, to make FTC agree with this, you first need to see the $1$ as some function's derivative. It is there where orientation appears. In this business of FTC and the role of orientation it pays off to go up in dimension, to look at integration not on $\mathbb{R}$. On $\mathbb{R}$, an orientation is too "natural", tangent spaces all look the same. Paradoxically, things get obscured by the simplicity, in this case.

Answer (score 4):

The Riemann or Lebesgue integral of a function $h$ on an interval $[a,b]$ is defined without any orientation on the interval. The concept of orientation is never mentioned when first defining integration.

I rarely see orientation mentioned in an introduction to Lebesgue integration, especially if the fundamental theorem of calculus is not discussed. A measure is always assumed to be positive (or at least nonnegative) and the integral of a measure is always positive. There is no orientation assigned to the support of the measure. Note that when working with abstract measure spaces, there isn't even a well-defined concept of orientation (and therefore no straightforward analogue of the fundamental theorem of calculus).

Orientation appears implicitly when defining the *notation* of a Riemann integral (or a Lebesgue integral over a connected interval). The integral of $h$ over $[a,b]$, where $a\le b$, is denoted
$$\int_a^b h(x)\,dx. $$
But a new convention is also introduced, namely that
$$\int_b^a h(x)\,dx = -\int_a^b h(x)\,dx. $$
This convention was introduced specifically to make the equation
$$\int_a^b f’(x)\,dx = f(b) - f(a)$$
hold even if $a>b$.

In hindsight, we now recognize that the fundamental theorem of calculus is about the integral of a derivative over an oriented interval. An orientation of an interval is the same as putting an arrow on it, which is equivalent to labeling one point the start point and the other the end point. The fundamental theorem of calculus states simply that the integral of $f$ over an oriented interval is the value of $f$ at the end point minus the value of $f$ at the start point.

Since orientation is needed for a single variable Stokes’ theorem, it is not surprising that it also plays a crucial role in the multivariable Stokes’ theorem (which really should be called the fundamental theorem of calculus).

Answer (score -3):

> In what piece is the "orientation" a→b encoded?

The **ordered pair** of points $(a,b)$ gave this curve a **direction** and induced the positive **orientation** for the point $b$ and negative -- for the $a$, which is used in the RHS (see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4697720/73934) as the whole equation is the Stokes theorem of differential geometry.

**EDIT** following OP's restriction of the integration path to an interval on the real line. That's fine but be careful if your teacher like a commenter @TedShifrin below defines interval $(a,b)$ to be the set $\{x\in \Bbb R: a<x<b\}$. By that definition $(2, -3)$ is a null set. Yet, integral over $(2, -3)$ is not identical 0. They can try to amend their definition for $b<a$ etc. But the right way to specify the direction or "orientation" in this case is to simply decide which point is beginning and which is the end. So, an **ordered pair** of points (e.g. on a real line)! The OP is right too to try and bring it out of the school calculus into differential geometry context, while the measure theory and Lebesgue vs. Riemann integration are a red herring in this question.

Comment: @Ted, look under the integral in OP, it's literally $(a,b)$ -- an ordered pair (of the end points of a curve one assumes). Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair . And the OP never said "interval", by the way, did you notice? "Sounds like a ChatGPT answer" -- is that a joke? Didn't expect it from a fellow mathematician. What if people start writing it under your answers, would you like that?

Comment: No, the *interval* $(a,b)$ denotes the set $\{x\in \Bbb R: a<x<b\}$. Similarly, $[a,b]$ denotes the *closed interval* $\{x\in \Bbb R: a\le x\le b\}$. The OP doesn't need to say the word, because it's understood by (almost) all readers.

Comment: You use *interval* but neither OP nor my answer had that word. The differential-forms tag suggested they were looking for other contexts and interpretations as well. Their $a \to b$ notation also could mean a curve going from a point $a$ to a point $b$. Surely their diff. form only depends on the $x$ coordinate, but in the context of DG, points a and b didn't have to be on the real line. Look, the OP is a bit ambiguous, starting from the opening Lebesgue integration. Others answered that well. Erase the differential-forms tag and I'll delete my answer. Are you taking back your ChatGPT comment?

Comment: I'm sorry but yes, the left hand side is meant to be integration using an Lebesgue integral, across the interval. In the original post it was even $\int_{(a,b)}f'(x) d\lambda = f(b) - f(a)$ to make it clear that I'm assuming the Lebesgue measure, but for some reason someone edited it and changed it to $dx$. I tagged it with differential forms, because differential forms are the field where it's easy to see that orientation matters explicitly, and so I thought it might be good to provide some context.

Comment: @Jake1234 I strongly disapprove of the edit that was made to your question. If I were you, I would roll it back so that the question is notated the way you wrote it. A surprisingly thought-provoking question, by the way.

Comment: @TedShifrin see my edit if you want to continue discussion. As for your opening snide, defamatory comment, I conclude you really meant it and stand by it. I have flagged it as unfriendly/unkind/rude/condescending.

Comment: @rych I think you have some confusion over what the OP is asking. The point of Lebesgue integral is that we integrate over a *set*. In this case the set is the *interval* $(a,b)=\{x|a<x<b\}$. But sets don't have orientation, and thus we have OP's question.

Comment: @DavidRaveh I appreciate that, and others have tried to answer from that point of view. But there's also the FTC at play here, and the differential-form tag. This answer provides a link to the Stokes theorem, see also the ending of Deane's answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4742219/73934