# How to integrate on a complex interval?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

In textbook,it gives me a theorem:$w(t) \in C^{1}([a,b]),then \int^{b}_{a}w^{'}(t)dt=w(b)-w(a)$,How do I deal with the case where a,or b is a not real number?For example:$\int^{ \frac{\pi}{4}i}_{0}e^{it}dt=?$，It is different from definition,I can't integrate the real part and the imaginary part separately.I dont know how to handle $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}i] $ and integrand is a real-valued function.

Comment: One the notation $C([a,b])$, it is implicit that $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. Besides, what does $\int_0^{\frac\pi4i}e^{it}\,\mathrm dt$ mean?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ would be real numbers here. This theorem is technically also true for complex numbers if interpreted carefully. For complex differentiable functions in an open simply connected set, the integral from $a\to b$ is independent of the path chosen

Comment: Hi,@José Carlos Santos
.There is a lecture note where the problem from,https://users.math.msu.edu/users/shapiro/teaching/classes/425/fund_thm.pdf  
 <br/>I also dont know what the$\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}i}_{0}e^{it}dt$ mean .Thank you sir.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos,The problem is form exercise 1

Comment: Substitute $-i t=x$ to remove the imaginary bound and evaluate or evaluate the antiderivative and apply the theorem. They should give the same result

Comment: Then treat a and b as the end points of the path (could be just a connecting straight line for example) of integration, as I answered here on a (related) question of orientation https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4742156/73934. @Lee Mosher answer below is correct with enough detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general there is no well-defined integral between two complex numbers.

But there is a theory of path integration: if $\gamma : [a,b] \to \mathbb C$ is a path in the complex plane, and if $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is a continuous function then one can define the path integral
$$\int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \, dt
$$
One of the things you learn in a complex analysis course is that if $f$ is a holomorphic function on the whole plane then $f$ has a complex antiderivative $F : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$, i.e. $F'(z)=f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$, and furthermore there is a version of the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$\int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \, dt = F(\gamma(b)) - F(\gamma(a))
$$
By a somewhat severe abuse of notation, perhaps one might write the first integral in the format
$$\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f(\gamma(t)) \, dt
$$
which sorta-kinda matches what you have written in your post, although I would not advise that in general.

Anyway, you could work this out for the case
$$\gamma : [0,\pi/4] \to \mathbb C, \qquad \gamma(t) = i \, t 
$$
$$\gamma(0) = 0 \qquad \gamma(1) = \frac{\pi}{4} \, i
$$
$$f(z) = e^{z}, \qquad f(\gamma(t)) = e^{it}
$$
Using antiderivative $F(z) = e^{z}$ (and continuing the abuse of notation) you get
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4} i} e^{it} \, dt = F(\pi / 4) - F(0) = e^{\pi/4} - 1
$$